# Installation of postgresql-15 seems to fail

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, upgrade

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question - I am a developer not a sysadmin.

Since running apt-get update/upgrade on my ubuntu VM (Oracle VirtualBox) I cannot seem to get my postgresql database online.  I believe this is may be because postgresql-15 has been upgraded from beta-3 to beta-4.

This is a real nuisance for me because it has trashed our development environment. (I am assuming when we are ready to release 15 will be fully available and I would really like to be able to use `merge` statements in my code)

I wiped postgresql from the host and am now attempting a fresh install following [these instructions](https://nextgentips.com/2022/08/12/how-to-install-postgresql-15-beta-on-ubuntu-22-04/).

At Step 3. `sudo -u postgres psql`  I receive the follwing error : `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

which, essentially, is the problem I was faced with after the failed upgrade (despite having run `systemctl start postgresql`)

Can anyone advise what it is I need to do to get postgres-15 (preferably beta-4) up and running?

---

```
hugh@ububtuvm:~$ systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor p>
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-09-18 10:47:19 UTC; 31min ago
    Process: 2349 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2349 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 905us

Sep 18 10:47:19 ububtuvm systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 18 10:47:19 ububtuvm systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.


hugh@ububtuvm:~$ journalctl -xeu postgresql.service
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit postgresql.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A stop job for unit postgresql.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1675.
Sep 18 10:47:19 ububtuvm systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postgresql.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postgresql.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1675.
Sep 18 10:47:19 ububtuvm systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit postgresql.service has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit postgresql.service has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 1675.
```

---

```
root@ubuntuvm:/home/hugh# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
# postgresql.service is the meta unit for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on
# the system at once. Conceptually, this unit is more like a systemd target,
# but we are using a service since targets cannot be reloaded.
#
# The unit actually managing PostgreSQL clusters is postgresql@.service,
# instantiated as postgresql@15-main.service for individual clusters.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(installed by apt install)

---

I found [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt/FAQ#Development_snapshots) which contains the following paragraphs.

> After updating from an alpha or beta release I get an error about
> CATALOG_VERSION After upgrading from an alpha or beta package, I get
> an error like:
>
> The database cluster was initialized with CATALOG_VERSION_NO X, but
> the server was compiled with CATALOG_VERSION_NO Y. This is because the
> PostgreSQL data format can change between alpha releases - and
> occasionally even between beta releases if there's a really pressing
> need.
>
> If you need to access the old data, you will need to use the package
> version you were running before, and use pg_dump or pg_upgrade. The
> necessary binaries should have been saved in /var/tmp/postgresql*.
> Alternatively, look for the old packages in your
> /var/cache/apt/archives.

I am still struggling, though - I have not found the previous version anywhere yet.

Comment: Can you share the output of `systemctl status postgresql` and `journalctl -xeu postgresql.service`?

Comment: @skipper - hey, thanks for the very quick response

Comment: @larsks - the service definition may have been already installed from the beta-3 installation (which worked).

Comment: It looks like the ubuntu postgres unit does some funky stuff with systemd generators, which means things like `journalctl -u postgres` probably won't give us the information we're looking for. I'm taking a closer look at how things are set up right now (and I've removed my previous comment).

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has some clever support for running multiple postgres instances. The `postgresql.service` unit is just a dummy unit: it does nothing but run `/bin/true`. This may seem useless, but it's not! The key is that it is the *dependencies* of this unit that are important, and those are generated dynamically at boot time by `/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator`.

This looks at all the `/etc/postgresql/*/*/postgresql.conf` files on your system and uses these to generate instances of the `postgresql@.service` template unit.

When you install the `postgresql-15` package, this should:

1. Provide the file `/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf` (and other files in that directory), and
2. Automatically start the `postgresql@15-main.service` unit.

I've reproduced this on an Ubuntu 22.04 system, where I started with `postgresql-14`, then installed `postgresql-15` following the link in your question, and now I have:

```
root@ubuntu:~# systemctl list-units postgresql\*
  UNIT                       LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
  postgresql.service         loaded active exited  PostgreSQL RDBMS
  postgresql@14-main.service loaded active running PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main
  postgresql@15-main.service loaded active running PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main
```

I can successfully connect to the database, but since here I'm running two different postgres instances I need to specify an explicit port. Looking at the config files in `/etc/postgresql/...`, I see that my postgres 15 instance is using port 5433, so I run:

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo -u postgres psql -p 5433
psql (15beta4 (Ubuntu 15~beta4-1.pgdg22.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

---

If the Postgresql 15 service fails to start, to see the service status I would run:

```
systemctl status postgresql@15-main.service
```

And to see the logs I would run:

```
journalctl -u postgresql@15-main.service
```

Comment: thanks for the information.  I removed postgres-14 some time ago.  I will start again from scratch with postgres-14, then add 15 and see what I can glean from that.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do that: I would just take a look at your postgres 15 configuration: You know from the above which service to look at for error messages, so I would start there. You can also double check to see which port the postgres 15 instance is using; this affects the unix socket name, as I demonstrated here.

Comment: my 'base' error with a single instance of postgres-15 is  "database files are incompatible with server".  This started to occur when apt upgraded.  I have no postgres-14 currently, just a single 15/main cluster.  I believe what I need to do is get 15-beta-3 running again so I can dump the database, rerun the upgrade, then import.

Comment: I solved my problem by copying the data files from the ubuntu vm to a new Fedora vm.  Beta-3 was easy to find as rpms.  From there I did a pg_dumpall which I was able to import into the beta-4 db.